# Gulpfile to turn sass to css starting but not finishing

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am very new to gulp and sass, but trying to create a gulpfile that will take and scss file and turn it into a css file (this seems like it is a very common thing that lots of people do). I am following along this tutorial - https://youtu.be/nusgoj74a3Y?t=1301 - but it seems to be a bit outdated.

My directory looks like this

-xxx

--gulpfile

--src

---Assets

----scss

-----default.scss

----css

My gulpfile looks like this:

```
'use strict';

//dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');


//////////////////
// - SCSS/CSS - //
//////////////////

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

//compile css
gulp.task('compile_scss', function(){

    gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));

});

//detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function() {
    return gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, gulp.series('compile_scss'));
});

//run tasks
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch_scss'));
```

and when I run it I get this:

```
[20:39:12] Using gulpfile ~/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/gulpfile.js
[20:39:12] Starting 'default'...
[20:39:12] Starting 'watch_scss'...
```

I believe it is supposed to finish these tasks not just start them.

Also I believe it is supposed to take the scss file from the scss directory and then put a css file in the css directory which it does not do.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are triggering a watch there, try modifying any of your scss files, and watch the terminal transpile to CSS ;)

you could add alternatively something like

```
gulp.task('getCSS', gulp.series('compile_scss'));
```

and then run `gulp getCSS` to get the CSS

Comment: You're right I am triggering responses I don't know why I didn't notice. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason it seems to only detect the first change made. Do you know how to make it detect continuously?

Comment: it should be waching, sure you are not changing a file from outside `'./src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';` ?

Comment: Yes I am only changing the default.scss file. I get `Starting 'compile_scss'...` once but not after the first time.

Comment: where is located that file? if its not under ../scss/something/here then you need to also add that to the watch cnfig, as i suspect is the main you have it under ../scss/ without the midle ** specifed dir

Comment: changing var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss'; to var SCSS_SRC = ['./src/Assets/scss/*.scss', './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss']; should do the trick for you, better create a new var as i see you use it in other places also

Comment: Unfortunately I’m still getting the same issue. I don't think it is the cnfig because it is still working correctly but only for the first change. My scss file is in src/Assets/scss. Is there another line I need in my watch task?

Comment: that is the problem, your scss file is in src/Assets/scss. and you are telling to watch /src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss whichdoes not include files in the folder you mention you have the file

Comment: Take the `return` statement out of your `watch` task.  I bet `watch` will run more than once then.

Comment: Hey Mark. When I completely remove the return statement and run gulp, I get errors that say `[23:38:22] The following tasks did not complete: default, watch_scss
[23:38:22] Did you forget to signal async completion?` If you meant just taking out the word 'return' the program works the same; working only for the first change detected

Comment: You do need a `return` in front of  `    gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)` in your `compile_scss` task.

Comment: Otherwise your watch_scss task is just fine. "My scss file is in src/Assets/scss." And that absolutely is included in './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss'. The ** can indicate no directory so you are good.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Mark!

Comment: Yeah I think the only real problem was not having the `return` in the compile task, the return in the watch task seems optional - I don't usually see one there.  Glad you got it working.